# Mocking a default export function with Jest: TypeError: (0 , _sampleFunction).default is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have the following files:

**sampleFunction.ts:**

```js
export default (x: number) => x * 2;
```

**testFile:**

```js
import sampleFunction from './sampleFunction';

export default () => {
  const n = sampleFunction(12);
  return n - 4;
};
```

**testFile.test.ts:**

```js
import testFile from './testFile';

const mockFn = jest.fn();

jest.mock('./sampleFunction', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockFn,
}));

test('sample test', () => {
  testFile();
  expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();
});
```

When I run `testFile.test.ts`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , _sampleFunction).default is not a function
```

How can I mock `sampleFunction.ts` with Jest when it has a default exported function?

Comment: `=> ({ default: mockFn })`?

Comment: With your latest version (and various assumptions around setup it'd be nice if we didn't have to make) I get `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockFn' before initialization`, not `TypeError: (0 , _sampleFunction).default is not a function`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When mocking a default export, you need to pass both `default` and `__esModule` to jest:

```js
const mockFn = jest.fn();

jest.mock("./sampleFunction", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: mockFn,
}))
```

Comment: Thanks! But I tried as well and I'm getting the same answer (I updated my question with your update).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I found that using [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) worked for me. I also had to pass in a mockImplemention to prevent the real function from being called.

```
import * as sampleFunction from './sampleFunction';
test('sample test', () => {
    const exportListSpy = jest.spyOn(sampleFunction, 'default').mockImplementation(() => undefined);
    testFile();
    expect(exportListSpy).toBeCalled();
});
```